# How do you say that you are doing a "surface-level" study of something?

Tags: translation

Example sentence: *I did a surface-level study of German grammar.*

This would mean that I didn't go too deep in my study of German grammar; I stayed at the surface level and got just a basic overview.

My guesses would be somehow joining two words: *surfacnivela*, or *surfaconivela*, or *surfaco-nivela*.  I can't find any word like this in the dictionary and I'm not sure about all the rules regarding the joining of two words.

Or, I can use the word *malprofunda*.  But, I'm not sure if that word conveys the same meaning as *surface-level* does in English.

> My attempts:
>
> 1) *Mi faris malprofundan studon de Germana gramatiko.*
>
> 2) *Mi nur malprofunde studis la Germanan gramatikon.*

How should I say this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestions would be *sendetala* or *unua* or *prepara*.

- *Mi faris sendetalan studon de la germana gramatiko.*

I think *surfaca* would be understood. Otherwise *fari superrigardon* ("overview") or just *studeton*.

*Malprofunda* and *supraĵa* are fine but might sound self-condemnatory.

Comment: *Surfaca* absolutely is a good choice - it was the first one to spring to mind for me. If by "surface level" Chris also means "superficial" I would say it's the best choice.

From "La Ondoj de Esperantoj": *Plu sekvis analizo de la bazaj nocioj, miaguste, sufiĉe naiva kaj surfaca*

Answer (score 4):

Your examples are pretty OK.

Another possibilities are (additionally to the answers from Andrew):

- *Mi nur baznivele studis la germanan gramatikon*
- *Mi superrigarde studis  la germanan gramatikon*